# Adding command to CreatePipeline() vs Using Commands.Add()

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I'm having some trouble understanding the difference between the following code snippets:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

Console.WriteLine("#------ TidyScript ------#");

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline("C:\\\"Program Files\"\\\"tidy 5.8.0\"\\bin\\tidy.exe teste.html > teste_tidy.html ");


var results = pipeline.Invoke();

foreach (var result in results)
{
  Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

The above snippet executes smoothly and outputs my desired result, which is a corrected version of an badly formed html file. However, the following code:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

Console.WriteLine("#------ TidyScript ------#");

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

Command myCommand = new Command("C:\\\"Program Files\"\\\"tidy 5.8.0\"\\bin\\tidy.exe teste.html > teste_tidy.html ");
pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

var results = pipeline.Invoke();

foreach (var result in results)
{
  Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

Gives out an unhandled exception:

> Unhandled exception.
> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term
> 'C:"Program Files""tidy 5.8.0"\bin\tidy.exe teste.html >
> teste_tidy.html ' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or executable program.         Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

What is the difference between adding the previous command directly onto CreatePipeline() and adding after by using pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand)? Another use case I tried was the ls command. On the first example, I used CreatePipeline("ls ..") which worked perfectly, but the latter example's output was a CommandNotFoundException as well.

Comment: Look at the exception.  There are double quotes in the filename path.

Comment: The command string is the same in both the example that works and the example that fails - `"C:\\\"Program Files\"\\\"tidy 5.8.0\"\\bin\\tidy.exe teste.html > teste_tidy.html "`. Although strange looking, `C:\"Program Files"\"tidy 5.8.0"\bin\tidy.exe teste.html` is valid.

Comment: @RicardoP It may be worth testing with the following - `@"""C:\Program Files\tidy 5.8.0\bin\tidy.exe"" teste.html > teste_tidy.html "`. This is a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) where the path and name for `tidy` are enclosed in one set of quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`runspace.CreatePipeline()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.createpipeline#system-management-automation-runspaces-runspace-createpipeline(system-string))  expects a *piece of PowerShell source code* as its argument.
- For equivalent functionality via a pipeline's [`.Commands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.commandcollection) collection, call its `.AddScript()` method.

  - There's *no* need for a instantiating [`Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command),which itself represents only a *single, specific command*, and to which parameter values (arguments) would have to be added via its `.Parameters` collection.
  - Whatever you pass to a `Command` constructor is interpreted as the name or path of a command *only* - *not* a complete PowerShell statement. Mistakenly passing a complete statement - a command *with arguments* - results in the error you saw.

---

As an aside, I suggest simplifying your `.CreatePipeline()` call as follows:

```
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(
  @"& ""C:\Program Files\tidy 5.8.0\bin\tidy.exe"" teste.html > teste_tidy.html"
);
```

---

**Taking a step back**:

Unless you need to manage runspace creation explicitly, you can take advantage of the higher-level [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell) API, which allocates a default runspace and allows you to simplify your code to:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

Console.WriteLine("#------ TidyScript ------#");

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {

  var results = ps.AddScript(
    @"& ""C:\Program Files\tidy 5.8.0\bin\tidy.exe"" teste.html > teste_tidy.html"
  ).Invoke();

  foreach (var result in results)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
  }
}
```